# Disable Button Zurb Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb's Foundation data-abide in a form and would like to disable the submit button until the form is valid (e.g. valid email address).

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript on your submit button to prevent the default behavior.  Then you can listen for `'formvalid.zf.abide'` and `'forminvalid.zf.abide'` to submit or add custom error handling

```
<form data-abide novalidate id="testform">
  <label>
    Amount
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-label">$</span>
      <input class="input-group-field" id="exampleNumberInput" type="number" required pattern="number"/>

    <span class="form-error" data-form-error-for="exampleNumberInput">Amount is required.</span>
    </div>
  </label>
</form>
```

.

```
//add event handler to your submit button to prevent the form submit
//and call abide validation
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('submit clicked')
  $('#testform').foundation('validateForm')
})

//listen for the abide validation event and submit form
$(document).on('formvalid.zf.abide', function(event, form){
  console.log('form is valid')
  form.submit()
})
```